# setOnItemClickListener within Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

This is the error I receive:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Why can't I do something like this? I've pasted the `View` class that exists within my custom `Adapter` class:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.notifications_listview_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.notificationText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationText);
            holder.time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.profilePicture = (ImageView) (convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture));
            holder.notificationsIcon = (ImageView) (convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationsIcon));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ParseObject notifications = mNotifications.get(position);

        Date createdAt = notifications.getCreatedAt();
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        String convertedDate = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(createdAt.getTime(), now, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS).toString();

        holder.username.setText(notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME));
        holder.notificationText.setText(notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT));
        holder.time.setText(convertedDate);
        holder.profilePicture = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);

        if (notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE).equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_LIKE)) {
            holder.notificationsIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed_full);
        }

        if (notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE).equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_CYCLE)) {
            holder.notificationsIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_saved);
        }

        if (notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE).equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_EDIT)) {
            holder.notificationsIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_edit_feed);
        }

        holder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGalleryActivity(notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID));
            }
        });

        holder.profilePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGalleryActivity(notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID));
            }
        });

        holder.notificationsIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FeedActivitySingle.class);
                intent.putExtra(FeedActivitySingle.EXTRA_DESIGN, notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_FEED_OBJECT_ID));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FeedActivitySingle.class);
                    intent.putExtra(FeedActivitySingle.EXTRA_DESIGN, notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_FEED_OBJECT_ID));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
```

I want to set an `onItemClickListener` on one of the `listView` items in the Adapter. Why can't I do this? The error is thrown here where I've defined the `listView`:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

What should I do? All the regular ClickListeners work but I want the user to be able to select the `listView` item in the Adapter itself.

**Edit (Answer):**

Problem resolved! Just had to put my `onItemClickListener` in the `onCreate` method of the main activity where the custom `Adapter` was initialized.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Voila! It works.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            List<ParseObject> notifications = adapter.getNotifications();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) method looks for children:

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

The `ListView` is a parent of the `convertView` so the `findViewById` is returning null.

Why not set the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` that you are creating the layout in?

Comment: I would but then I can't get the string attached to the notifications variable. Conceptually, your method works, but for my specific problem I need to adjust some things. Thanks!

Comment: The `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` gives you the position of the item clicked. Which in turn you can use in the `getItem` method of your adapter to retrieve the `Object` clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The convertView variable is a row in the listView, because this the method findViewById.

```
convertView.findViewById()
```

Always return null.

if you want to do that u can do this.

```
convertView.setOnClicListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=newIntent(mContext,FeedActivitySingle.class);
                intent.putExtra(FeedActivitySingle.EXTRA_DESIGN, notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_FEED_OBJECT_ID));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```